# Samba accessible from same machine but not from external network

Tags: networking, server, samba, sharing

So I got samba configured on a remote Ubuntu 16.04 server but whenever I try to access it from either windows 10 or another ubuntu machine remotely, I get an error that the folder could not be found. It's worth noting that I'm trying to connect directly using the IP and not the hostname

When I try to connect using smbclient or list the folders from the same server, it connects just fine and I can see the shares.

```
root@hostname:~# smbclient -L //<ip is here>/home -U user
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter user's password:
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    home            Disk      home
Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]
```

When I try the same command from the remote ubuntu machine, it doesn't work.

See below my /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
    [global]

    ## Browsing/Identification ###

    # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
       workgroup = WORKGROUP

    # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field
            server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

    # Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
    # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
      wins support = yes

    # WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
    # Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
    ;   wins server = w.x.y.z

    # This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
       dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
interfaces = eth0 lo
guest account= nobody

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######

# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller".
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user


############ Misc ############


# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[home]
 comment=home
 path=/home/myhome/share
 browseable=Yes
 read only = yes
guest ok=yes
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> interfaces = eth0 lo

Well ... for one  ... unless you went out of your way to rename it you don't have an interface named eth0. You may have one labelled something like enp0s3.

Run the following command to find out:

```
ifconfig
```

Or just leave the entire line out of smb.conf. Samba will figure this out by itself.